# Wait in activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I have a class that has a service:

```
private ServiceConnection conn = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        service = ((MyService.LocalBinder)service).getService();
        isBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        service = null;
        isBound = false;
    }
};
```

I also have this method:

```
public boolean isBound() {
    return isBound;
}
```

In my activity I create an instance of the class. However, the service does not connected immediately.

In the activity, how can I wait the `isBound()` returns `true` without blocking the activity?

Comment: What is the idea of this construction? Why not bind the activity to the service directly?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't. By the way, you can also notify the world that your service has correctly connected with a `BroadcastReceiver`

Answer (score -1):

In your service class send broadcast:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.intent.service.connected");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In your activity catch the intent:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.intent.service.connected");
    this.registerReceiver(new Receiver(), filter);
}


 private class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

    // your codes

 }

}
```